# Changing directory echoes "Directory: <pwd>"

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu, gnu-screen, xterm

I have an annoying problem when using Screen on my SLED10 machine. When changing directory (cd, chdir, pushd/popd) the resulting path is echoed in the terminal.

```
user@/home/user> cd ..
Directory: /home
user@/home>
```

This problem only seem to exist in Screen. I have checked my prompt and it does not contain anything related to this behavior. I am using tcsh/xterm.

How do I get rid of the echo of the directory?!

Best Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Does it behave the same in sh, bash? Try to search string 'Directory: ' in configuration files (in /etc and home directories).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `cd` has been overridden with an alias or a function.

Once in `screen`, use:
`alias cd` to see if there is an alias and 
`declare -f` to check your functions.

Comment: I've checked for any alias but cannot find any. declare is not recognized on my machine.

Comment: Well, It seems I didn't check the alias list enough:

    cwdcmd (echo "Directory: $cwd" > /dev/$tty)